# Is this an Integral Domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let X be a non-empty set, and set $P(X)$ the set of all subsets of X
>   with addition and multiplication:
>
> $A+B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) $ and $A \cdot B = A \cap B $

I am just wondering if I have thought about this correctly - I have that this a commutative, unital ring - but NOT an integral domain.

Checking the ring axioms, I have that

(i) Commutativity of addition is straightforward, clearly addition is closed.

(ii) Checking $(A+B)+C = A+ (B+C)$ I have that:

$$ (A+B)+C = [[(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)] \cup C] \setminus [[(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)] \cap C]$$

Thus if $x \in (A+B)+C$ then there are 3 cases: either (1) $x \in A \setminus (B \cup C)$, (2) $x \in B \setminus (A \cup C)$, (3) $x \in C \setminus (A \cup B)$.

Then,

$$ A+(B+C) = [A \cup [[(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)]] \setminus [[A \cap [(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)]]$$

and checking if $x \in A+(B+C)$ yields the same 3 cases as above. Would this be correct?

(iii)I take the empty set as the zero element: $A + \phi = (A \cup \phi ) \setminus (A \cap \phi ) = A$

(iv) I take each set A as it's own inverse $A + A = (A \cup A ) \setminus (A \cap A ) = \phi$

(v) Multiplication is closed

(vi) Multiplication is associative

(vii) Checking $A \cdot (B+C) = A \cdot B + A \cdot C$ I have:

$$A \cdot (B+C) = A \cap [(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)] $$ So there are two cases: (i) $ x \in A \cap B$ and $x \notin C$, or (ii) $ x \in A \cap C$ and $x \notin B$

On the otherhand:

$$ A \cdot B + A\cdot C = [(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)] \setminus [(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C)]$$ yielding the same two cases as above. So it is indeed a ring.

The ring is clearly commutative under addition, and I take the identity as the set $X$ itself, since $A \cap X = A$. However, $A \cap B = \phi$ whenever $A$ and $B$ do not intersect. So it is not an integral domain.

Have I thought about this correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $A+(B+C)$ has four cases - there is also $A\cap B\cap C$.

Comment: It is not a domain, provided $X$ is empty or it has more than one element. In the case $|X|=1$, $P(X)$ is the two element field.

Comment: @Michael - Are you sure? On the the RHS of the $=$, the left term - doesn't that exclude the possibility of being in $B \cap C$?

Comment: The intersection of all three is not in $A+B$, but it is in $C$, so it is in $(A+B)+C$.  Also, it is not in $(B+C)$, but is in $A$, so it is in $A+(B+C)$.

Comment: @Michael - but you have to use the definition of addition as provided don't you? Addition is not defined as simply add possibilities of $C$.

Comment: The intersection of all three is in $A\cap B$, so it is not in $A+B$.  It is in the union of $A+B$ and $C$, but not in the intersection of $A+B$ and $C$, so it is in $(A+B)+C$.

Comment: @Michael - sorry, I am not really understanding..based on the definition of addition, is what I have on the RHS of the = for $(A+B)+C$ correct above? If it is - then isn't an element which is in A and B and C not in the set on the LHS of the set-minus sign (because then it is in $A \cap B$)? So if it is already not in there - whatever is to the right of the set-minus sign doesn't add elements to the set - wouldn't that be correct?

Comment: It is not in $(A\cup B)\backslash(A\cap B)$ but it is in $((A\cup B)\backslash(A\cap B))\cup C$

Comment: @Michael - ahh I am getting it. Dang all the set notation can be so confusing! It is just an extra case though isn't it? We still have $(A+B)+C = A+(B+C)$ don't we? Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

you may think of the power set of $X$ as a space $2^X$ of functions  from $X$ to the two-element field $\mathbb{F}_2$. since the codomain is a field there is a natural way of defining multiplication and addition as pointwise operations in $\mathbb{F}_2$. each set may be identified with its characteristic function. the associative law for addition, for example, or the distributive law, are a consequence of the same laws in $\mathbb{F}_2$